# How to transfer states of each react components to store?

Tags: state, react-redux

I have a very simple question: why in a bunch each of the react component uses its state? 
I believe that you need to transfer the state of all the components used in the app to the one redux store. 
Instead of synchronizing nested parent and childs components states, by the component's key, find its state in the standalone redux store

[How to synchronize states from redux-form Field components and cascading DropdownList react-widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855510/how-to-synchronize-states-from-redux-form-field-components-and-cascading-dropdow)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you model the application. For example you can have one reducer for each container component of you application. You still can keep state in your components, but once you need to synchronize this state between components, you dispatch actions with the changes you need and then update the store. So every container that is tracking the part of the state that has changed, will receive those changes.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the way to connect a separate component to the general state of the application in the store is complicated, not out of the box! It was difficult for me to synchronize the state of the component Field from the redux-form and the internal component DropdownList of the react-widget